# Comparing two version of the same Website

Tags: html, css, svn

After a merge with a lot of conflicts I should have the two branches aligned and showing the same website. But actually this doesn't happen..

Is there a way to compare the output (html + css) of the two websites? How do you usually cope with this kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool:

http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php

You can compare just file names or can do a deeply comparisson with a byte-by-byte comparisson. It can also show a UI for comparing files next to each other.

It is really helpful for debugging and comparing two websites.

Answer (score 1):

Try using php and using the file_get_contents() function. Have 2 variables that gets each URL of the sire you want to compare.

So

$site_one = file_get_contents("http://google.com");

$site_one = file_get_contents("http://google.co.uk");

Echo both of them variables out and you should see the HTML :).

Comment: After that, use the explosion php function and explode \r\n so you get line breaks.